# Proof that Bose-Einstein condensation (BEC) discontinuity happens at the thermodynamic limit

Tags: statistical-mechanics, bose-einstein-condensate

From
http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/statphys/sp.pdf
page 89 (95/191 in the pdf file),

> We can see that by looking again at the expressions (3.30) and (3.31), which tell us

$$
z = \left( 1+ \frac{1}{n_0} \right)^{-1} = \left( 1 + \frac{1}{N} \frac{1}{ 1 - (T/T_c)^{3/2} } \right)^{-1}
$$
the author then analyzed $dz/dT$ and claimed the discontinuity will appear in $N\rightarrow \infty $. I am not sure how the author gets this conclusion.

If I take $T  \rightarrow T_c$, $1 − (T /T_c)^{3/2} \rightarrow 0$. For a finite $N$, $1/N$ will unable to cancel the singularity from $1/(1 − (T /T_c)^{3/2})$, but looks like finite number of particle leads to singularity.

Comment: No, it is not what Tong claims. Read that passage again.

Comment: I corrected from $T -> \infty$ to $N -> \infty$. But that does not answer my question.

Comment: Then what exactly is the question? How to arrive at the phase transition in the limit $N\to \infty$?

Comment: How to see the discontinuity only happens at $ N -> \infty$ as the author states "The difference is that while dz/dT is of order one above Tc, it is of order 1/N below Tc. In the thermodynamic limit, N → ∞, this results in the discontinuity that we saw above."?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the formulas you use are asymptotic expansions in the thermodynamic limit. However, this limit is in some sense pathological due to the emerging phase transition (not uniform). You’ll therefore need to be careful in estimating the error, and in your case, this explains the apparent singularity at the transition temperature.

Recall that $z$ is defined implicitly in terms of $T,N$ (in dimensionless units):
$$
N=NT^s\text{Li}_s(z)+\frac z{1-z}
$$
In the case of a gas, $s=D/2$, in the case of a harmonic trap, $s=D$, with $D$ the dimension of the system (in your case $s=3/2$). For $s>1$, you have Bose-Einstein condensation. The transition is only well defined in the thermodynamic limit, and occurs exactly at the critical temperature:
$$
T_c=\text{Li}_s(1)^{-1/s}=\zeta(s)^{-1/s}
$$
The previous equation perfectly well defines $z\in(0,1)$ since the RHS is increasing ranging in $\mathbb R_+^*$. At fixed finite $N$, $T$ is a smooth decreasing function in $z$, and you therefore do not have a transition.

Physically, it is more relevant to think in terms of the ground state occupation number:
$$
N_0 = \frac{z}{1-z}
$$
which is a smooth increasing function of $z$, so will capture just as well any phase transition. The phase transition in the thermodynamic limit is due to the change of scaling. For $T<T_c$, $N_0$ is extensive, so the finite quantity in the thermodynamic limit is $n_0 = N_0/N$, while for $T>T_c$, it is intensive so $N_0$ itself converges to a finite limit in the thermodynamic limit.

I'll reconcile this approach with your flawed argument. For $T<T_c$, in the thermodynamic limit, you indeed have at leading order in $N$:
$$
n_0 = 1-(T/T_c)^s
$$
However, this is not uniformly valid for $T<T_c$. This is why you cannot permute the limits $N\to\infty$ and $T\to T_c$. Your formula already shows you that there is going to be an issue as the limit is undefined ($0\times \infty$). Indeed, you are neglecting $o(N^0)$ terms which will dominate at finite $N$ as $T\to T_c$, so your apparent singularity gets smoothed out.

To get the correct behaviour at the transition, you need to use an intermediate scaling. For $1<s<2$ (which is your case), continuing the expansion:
$$
\text{Li}_s(z\to1) = \zeta(s)+\Gamma(1-s)(1-z)^{s-1}+o((1-z)^{s-1})
$$
it will be the second leading order term that will give the correct scaling at the transition. Namely, you can check that at the transition:
$$
N_0(T=T_c) = \left(-\frac{\Gamma(1-s)}{\zeta(s)}N\right)^{1/s}
$$
As expected, there is a separation of scale in the thermodynamic limit. It also allows you to estimate the region of validity of your previous formula. Essentially, it starts to fail when the two formulas for $N_0$ are of the same magnitude. Your formula is therefore only valid for:
$$
T_c-T\gg N^{1/s-1}
$$
As you can see, the domain of validity excludes a small neighbourhood of $T_c$, but shrinks to zero in the thermodynamic limit.

You'll notice that a similar argument holds in the $T>T_c$ phase. For $T\to T_c$, you have the intensive quantity diverging as (with a numerical prefactor):
$$
N_0 \propto (T-T_c)^{\frac1{1-s}}
$$
Once again, it is not uniformly valid for $T>T_c$, the region of validity depends on $N$:
$$
T- T_c\gg N^{1/s-1}
$$

Here, I illustrated the collapse in the BEC phase. The black dotted curve is the thermodynamic limit:
$$
n_0 = 1-(T/T_c)^s
$$
As $N\to\infty$, you do get a collapse, and the region of agreement grows to $(0,T_c)$, but beyond the region of agreement, the formula completely fails.
[image: BEC phase]

Analogously, I illustrated the collapse in the normal phase. The black dotted curve is the thermodynamic limit:
$$
\beta := 1/T  = \text{Li}_s\left(\frac{N_0}{1+N_0}\right)^{1/s}
$$
[image: normal phase]

To better understand the smooth transition, you can use the scaling:
$$
\begin{align}
T &= T_c+N^{1/s-1}\theta & N_0 &= N^{1/s}\tilde n_0
\end{align}
$$
In the thermodynamic limit, $\tilde n_0$ tends to a well defined function of $\theta$. You can even work it out to:
$$
\theta = -\frac{T_c}s\left(\frac{\Gamma(1-s)}{\zeta(s)}\tilde n_0^{1-s}+\tilde n_0\right)
$$
In our case $s=3/2$, you can even invert the relation using the quadratic formula. This demonstrates that under the correct scaling, you still have a smooth transition in the thermodynamic limit. It's just a crossover between the low energy modes captured by the asymptotics of the polylogarithm (first term) and the ground mode (second term).
[image: transition]

Hope this helps.